# Excel help: appropriate function for lookup/match cases

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

Got a huge dataset that is dynamically connected and used on one workbook (lets call it W1) and on another workbook (W2) are the data set that has to be updated firstly there (W2) and then on the main workbook (W1).

So on this workbook **W1** under is part of huge data set which is needed to be populated periodically, with some function or macro, but to avoid lot of manual labor. 
What I actually want is to lookup `Column U`both row/column context for matches from outside workbook (W2). But the problem are empty rows or rows that are gonna be added later on - labeled as `Reseviert` inside column where I dont wanna disrupt the calculation and function context. 
[image: W1]

On the second workbook **W2** that is under is data set that is gonna be uploaded with **(_)** in a case of not available or with **(1)** when its available, and that I have always to populate in a main table. 
[image: W2]

I tried to use index/match/match function but somehow it didnt work as I wanted. I cant figure it out but only to copy/paste it XYZ times inside Workbook, it is quite time consuming...

This is function: `IF(INDEX('0528-matrix.csv'!$A:$Y;MATCH(U80;'0528-matrix.csv'!$A:$A;0);MATCH(BE14;'0528-matrix.csv'!$1:$1;0));"n.k";"")`

This "nK" is just random name in a case of "match" from other table.

Any suggests??

Comment: Start by doing each of the matches separately, if they return as expected the add the index... then finally the if() as you don't say what the error is...

Comment: @SolarMike I just wanna empty cell in a case of an "error", when match isnt found. 
I will see it, thx

Comment: Try IF(INDEX('0528-matrix.csv'!$A:$Y;MATCH(U80;'0528-matrix.csv'!$A:$A;0);MATCH(BE14;'0528-matrix.csv'!$1:$1;0));"")

Comment: @SolarMike    '=IF(INDEX($U$14:$DC$138;MATCH(U17;'0528-matrix.csv'!$A:$A;0);MATCH(X$14;'0528-matrix.csv'!$1:$1;0))=0;X17="_";"n.k")'

I managed with this formula actually...but I cant figure how to get "blanks" instead of "zeros" and "n.k" when I got a match...I am just getting 0 and NA....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, not sure what you are really doing, but this is based on my best guess:

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(INDEX($U$14:$DC$138,MATCH(U20,'0528-matrix.csv'!$A:$A,0),MATCH(X$14,'0528-matrix.csv'!$1:$1,0)),"Check")=0,X17="_"),"n.k","")
```

So, I assumed the index result is an OR() with the test of cell X17, but you can use AND() if both need to be true...

The iferror() is to give the if() a false to work with as it needs to trap an error from the index() & match().

I also worked with if the index() returns a result then you should get "n.k", if not then it will give blank. You can swap those as they are just the if value_if_true and value_if_false.

Comment: What I am getting are 0 and NA fields, that is not what I want. That is reason I tried with this "=0,X17="_"),"n.k","")"  but it is not working properly. I wanted to give me "blanks" when it hit ( _ ) from  other workbook and (n.K) when it is 1 from other workbook.... thats the only thing. I think this is proper formula, from you and also from my side...but only that "logical" thing bothers me....  suggest?

Answer (score 0):

After couple of days of working and thinking...it was actually simple fucntion:

`=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('0528-matrix.csv'!$A:$Y;MATCH($U17;'0528-matrix.csv'!$A:$A;0);MATCH(X$14;'0528-matrix.csv'!$1:$1;0))=1;"n.k";"");"")`

Explanation:

In my case it is a huge chunk of data, which are updated on monthly basis, but considering 2 Workbooks, where second is gonna be updated with ( _ ) if part isnt compatible and with ( 1 ) if it is with Workbook 1.

But in Workbook 1 I cant put ( _ ) and ( 1 ) but blanks for ( _ ) and "n.k" or whatever for ( 1 ).

With index/match you can actually match all of them, but thing is this small "separation" in a case of both matches, thats the reason we have IF/IFERROR.